# Change behavior inside ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get an array of string like this `["create-user", "edit-user", "read-user", "delete-user"]` in console, now i want to pass it to view . 
My code :

```
  <tr ng-repeat="perm in permsAll">
        <td>
            {{perm == "create-user" : X ? ' '}}
         </td>
          <td>
            {{perm == "create-edit" : X ? ' '}}
         </td>
         ....
 </tr>
```

So i get all strings but not that what i want :( , i want if user have create-user for example make a X in td example `userX = createUser: X` if not have create-use it will be empty .

How to do it ? , i guess i must to use directive. and thanks ?

Comment: Try to use equality operation, not assignment: perm.contain == "create-user"

Comment: needs "==" or "==="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in different ways.

You can try to use a ng-switch or a ng-if or even a ng-show.

For example:

```
<td ng-if="perm.contain === 'create-user'>X </td>
```

If you want to use the code you have you have to change for something like:

```
<td>
   {{perm.contain === 'create-user' ? 'X' : ' '}}
</td>
```

edited: added literal string

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the wrong operator, try this:

```
{{perm.contain == "create-user" : X ? ' '}}
```

But your best bet would be like sexta said:

```
<td ng-show="perm.contain == 'create-user' ">X</td>
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Gustavo still empty in console log i get <td ng-show="perm.contain == 'create-user" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide">X</td>

Comment: But what are trying to print in the console? And now that i read your question again, do you really have a attribute called contain? Shouldnt it be <td ng-show="perm == 'create-user' ">{{perm}}</td>